# CSS Background - How would you do this?

Tags: html, background, css

I really need some help with a background on a website. You can see the image here:

[Link to image](http://img852.imageshack.us/i/testbg01.jpg/)

Now what i want is first of all to have the image placed in the top middle. Then i would like to have something like 10x250px (Width x Height) from the left of the image to be repeated - should a visitors screen resolution be wider than the image it won't seem like the site just stops at the edges.

I've tried several things, but it seems i keep running into different kind of technicalities that I'm not sure how to get around. So I would like to know how you would do it?

(The websites content will be 990px wide if that helps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to accomplish this so that it attempts to center for all screen resolutions so that there is never a bottom scrollbar.  bg.gif is your image ang bg_filler.gif is a 20px slice off of the side.

```
   <style>
   body 
   {
        background-image: url(bg_filler.gif);
        background-repeat: repeat-x; 
        background-color: #D1CDCA;
        margin: 0px;         
   }

   .backgroundPart
   {    
        height: 300px;
        background-image : url(bg.gif);
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;  
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px; 
   }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="backgroundPart">

    </div>

</body>
```

Here is a sample http://www.wesgrant.com/samples/BackgroundSample/default.html

Answer (score 2):

But the repeating image on your `<body>`, and put the other image background on your wrapper `<div>` (or similar).

Alternatively, you can use CSS3 for multiple background images on the same element. Won't be as compatible though.

Comment: Well i thought of this. The problem is that the non-repeating part of the image is about 1500px wide - won't that create a vertical scroller for people with a resolution below 1500px?

Comment: If the wrapper div is also 1500px wide, then yes of course. The background image will always be centered, so it will never be wider than the div.

Comment: So there is no other way to do it? The wrapper shouldn't be wider than 990px - so the background would be cut-off.

Comment: The wrapper can expand as much as it can, just have another div centered containing everything.

Comment: But that would still create a vertical scroller if the wrapper with the background is bigger than the viewable area of a visitors screen?

Comment: Just have it auto expand/100% width.

Comment: the image won't create a scroller if it's a background image it will crop to the div size.. just position it center

Answer (score 0):

Something like this style:

```
<style>
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:'repeating_image...';
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    }

#wrapper {
    width:990px;
    background-image:url(http://img852.imageshack.us/img852/4169/testbg01.jpg);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create two images, one for the body to repeat, and the other being the header that you already have. here is your image in a demo.
take a look at the source code to see how this works

http://luistovar.com/sodemo

No matter how large the screen resolution is now, the bg repeats.
Good luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
* {padding:0px; margin:0px;}
body {
background-image: url(repeat.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:top;
}

#header {
background-image: url(header.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:1600px;
height:252px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
-->
</style>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="header"></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```